# Ruby - Problem to test Object.class into Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, class

today, inside my code, if file exist, i try to do something if an Array don't contain specific class, but the test don't work.

```
def LoadPackagesDatabase
        packagesFiles = Dir['Packages/*.rb']
        packagesClass = []
        packagesFiles.each do |file|
            load file
            filename = file.sub('.rb', '')
            packagesClass.append(Object.const_get(filename.sub('Packages/','')).new)
        end

        if File.exist?("PackagesDatabase.rb")
            $PackagesDatabase = Marshal.load(File.read("PackagesDatabase.rb"))

            packagesClass.each do |package|
               if !$PackagesDatabase.include?(package.class)
                   $PackagesDatabase.append(package)
               end
            end
            File.delete("PackagesDatabase.rb")
            packagesDatabaseFile = File.open("PackagesDatabase.rb",'w')
            packagesDatabaseFile.write(Marshal.dump($PackagesDatabase))
            packagesDatabaseFile.close
        else
            $PackagesDatabase = packagesClass
            packagesDatabaseFile = File.open("PackagesDatabase.rb",'w')
            packagesDatabaseFile.write(Marshal.dump(packagesClass))
            packagesDatabaseFile.close
        end

    end
```

I don't would like to test if array contain the same object, but if array contain specific class.

Comment: To clarify, if you had `array = ['foo', 23, 42]` then `array.contains_class?(Numeric)` is true but `array.contains_class?(Time)` is false?

Answer (score 1):

`Array#include?` does a simple equality check. For more generic checks use [`any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-any-3F) and [`all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-all-3F), and [`none?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-none-3F). They all take blocks to do the comparison.

```
if $PackagesDatabase.none? { |item| item.is_a?(package.class) }
  $PackagesDatabase.append(package)
end
```

Note that I'm not using `item.class == package.class`, that requires an exact match. Instead I'm using `is_a?`. This ensures subclasses will also match. For example, `23.class == Numeric` is false but `23.is_a?(Numeric)` is true. Which you use depends on your exact circumstance, but in general you should use `is_a?` to make your code more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

One could use the mighty [Enumerable#grep](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep), which uses the method `===` for selection. Suppose, for example,

```
arr = [1, 'cat', 2.3]
```

One could write, for example:

```
arr.grep(Float).any?   #=> true
arr.grep(Numeric).any? #=> true
arr.grep(Complex).any? #=> false
arr.grep(Array).any?   #=> false
```

In evaluating `arr.grep(Float)` the method [Module#===](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D)<sup>1</sup> is used to make the following calculations:

```
Float === 1     #=> false 
Float === 'cat' #=> false
Float === 2.3   #=> true
```

One could instead write

```
arr.any? { |o| Float === o } #=> true
```

which has the advantage that it *short-circuits* the calculation, meaning that the enumeration of the elements of `arr` is halted if and when the block returns `true`. By contrast, `arr.grep(Float).any?` enumerates the entire array.

<sup>1. Note that `Float.method(:===).owner #=> Module`.</sup>